# How do I replace plain text image URLs in textnodes with img elements using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey

I'm a complete newbie to JavaScript, and I'm trying to make a Greasemonkey script that replaces image links with the actual image (as well as do other stuff that I'll do later on).

So I thought I could use the following.

```
var imagelinks = [
    "http*://*/*.jpg",
    "http*://*/*.png",
    "http*://*/*.gif"
];
```

All I am trying to do is using JavasScript (and/or jQuery), replace raw URL text within a "post-list-content-element" element with the image that that URL links to. In [this example](http://pastehtml.com/view/bhn6zqytf.html) I want to replace that URL with the actual image.

Comment: You made [this page](http://pastehtml.com/view/bhn6zqytf.html) as an example, but it has no links.  Are you trying to swap actual *links* (`<a>` tags) or raw URL-text?

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to replace that raw text with the image.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for adding the example link to your question, it really helped. I've removed my previous confused efforts.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('post-list-content-element');
[].forEach.call(items, function(item){
    item.innerHTML = item.innerHTML.replace(
            /http?:\/\/\S*?\.(jpg|png|gif)/g,
            '<img src=$&>');
});
```

A caveat: this assumes that there are no actual images already within your `post-list-content-element` divs.

Okay, here's a more general purpose version that only replaces within textnodes. I'll leave you to iron out the bugs :-)

```
var replaceInChildTextNodes = (function(){

    var eachChild, splits;

    eachChild = function(node, f){
        var children, parent = node;
        children = [].slice.apply(parent.childNodes);
        children.forEach(function(child){
            f(child, parent);
            eachChild(child, f);
        });
    };

    splits = function(s, regexp){
        var nonmatches=[], matches=[], i=0, j=0;
        while((match = regexp.exec(s))){
            j = match.index;
            nonmatches.push(s.substr(i, j-i));
            matches.push(match[0]);
            i = j + match[0].length;
            if(!regexp.global)
                break;
        }
        nonmatches.push(s.substr(i));
        return {nonmatches: nonmatches, matches: matches};
    };

    return function(nodes, regexp, replacer){
        [].forEach.call(nodes, function(node){
            eachChild(node, function(childNode, parent){
                var match, i=0, j=0, split, newNodes=[];
                if(childNode.nodeName === '#text'){
                    split = splits(childNode.nodeValue, regexp);
                    if(split.matches.length === 0)
                        return;
                    newNodes = [];
                    split.nonmatches.forEach(function(text, i){
                        if(text !== '')
                            newNodes.push(document.createTextNode(text));
                        if(split.matches[i])
                            newNodes.push(replacer(split.matches[i]));
                    });
                    newNodes.forEach(function(newNode){
                        parent.insertBefore(newNode, childNode);
                    });
                    parent.removeChild(childNode);
                }
            });
        });
    };
}());
```

Usage:

```
var parents = document.getElementsByClassName('post-list-content-element');
replaceInChildTextNodes(parents, /http?:\/\/\S*?\.(jpg|png|gif)/g, function(text){
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = text;
    return img;
});
```

It doesn't use String#split, so you don't need to worry about capturing groups in the regexp, and it respects the `g` flag.

Caveat: not cross-browser.

Comment: That appends the image to the end of the document, I was looking to replace the array with the actual image. That just displays 3 broken images.

Comment: Third attempt above. Have I understood you better?

Comment: I edited that code (replaced ByTagName with ByClassName, and a to post-list-content-element seeing as that is what (I think) it should be), and it still didn't work, nothing happens to the page I'm afraid. And no, that isn't what it should be, the link will be in plain text, like here: [link](http://pastehtml.com/view/bhn6zqytf.html)

Comment: I think you need to revise your question and provide some more information. It seems we're all having some difficulty understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: I thought it was simple... all I am trying to do is using JavasScript, replace raw URL text within a "post-list-content-element" element with the image that that URL links to. In [this example](http://pastehtml.com/view/bhn6zqytf.html) I want to replace that URL with the actual image.

Comment: this won't work as the text is not in a `<a>` tag. you can make test here: http://pastehtml.com/view/bhn7dx04l.html

Comment: Using the code from that last edit finally makes the image appear, but not on the new line, I think it deleted the line break tags.

Comment: No problem. Bear in mind that this is a quick hack however. If you have any actual images within your `post-list-content-element` divs, then their `src`s will be turned to garbage by this.

Comment: Re: `"Thank you very much for the help, everyone."`  If you found your solution please upvote any helpful answers and [accept the best answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) (or write your own if none of the answers quite, fully, got it).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          your script
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==
var exp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|].(gif|jpg|png))/ig;
$(".post-list-content-element").each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(exp,"<img src='$1' \\>"))
});
```

Comment: I just tried that, but as soon as the page loads it just shows a blank page with three broken images.

Comment: Where do you want to put your images?

Comment: I want to **replace** the link with the image.

Comment: Oh, I think I got your question now. You do not have the image array, you want to replace links ending by jpg, png and gif by the actual image, right?

Comment: Is the link in plain old text or is it in a `<a>` tag?

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. And it's plain text, inside a "post-list-content-element" class div.

Comment: let me do some tests and I'll edit my answer. You want to use the RegExp object.

Comment: I'm not sure, seeing as Greasemonkey scripts are .user.js files, however I have no idea if `@require` can be used for the jQuery part.

Comment: Yeah, I edited my answer with `@require`. However, it will work only if your `post-list-content-element` contain only images. Do you have a page example so we can test together?

Comment: It has text too, seeing as it would be inside a forum post. And here is a quick page I made: [link](http://pastehtml.com/view/bhn6zqytf.html)

Comment: Edited again to test if the element contains a string ending with an image extension

Comment: Just tested a new version on the following page (copy of yours with jquery inclusion): http://pastehtml.com/view/bhn7dx04l.html

Comment: I just tested and it does work from the Javascript debugger. I'm not that savvy with greasemonkey though...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a complete script that uses jQuery to create images from the URL-text:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Imagify image URL's
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include  http://pastehtml.com/view/bhn6zqytf.html
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

var textToImagify       = $(".post-list-content-element");

textToImagify.replaceWith ( function () {
    var imagifiedSrc    = $(this).html ();

    imagifiedSrc    = imagifiedSrc.replace (
                        /(https?:\/\/.+?\.(?:jpg|png|gif))/ig, '<img src="$1">'
                    );

    return imagifiedSrc;
} );
```

Reference:

- [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/)
- [replaceWith()](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=replaceWith)

**WARNING:**  Beware that mixing text, HTML, and regex is fraught with pitfalls.  If the problem becomes more complex than what you've indicated, you will need to use DOM-parsing techniques.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit outside of what you're looking for, but the fastest way I know of to change an image link would be to use jQuery and the following syntax:

```
$("img#your_image_id").attr("src", "your_image_location");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `document.getElementById('image').src` where 'image' is the id attribute of the img tag.

Comment: But I can't, the links don't have any ids/classes - it's just plain text.

Comment: I won't be able to edit the HTML code, it's on a forum, and the image link would be in the post class.